# Full Calendar and auto Filtering Events Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, fullcalendar, filtering

I am building a calendar application which requires certain events to display on the calendar based on the location that is being viewed. I have full calendar working in which it displays **ALL** the events in the database. I am trying to achieve an auto filter to only show the events that pertain to the location being viewed.

Current Setup (My Events Model is called "Campaigns" to align with my application)

**Campaign Controller**

```
def index
  @campaigns = Campaign.all
  @campaigns = @campaigns.after(params['start']) if (params['start'])
  @campaigns = @campaigns.before(params['end']) if (params['end'])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @campaigns }

  end
end
```

**Campaign Model**

```
belongs_to :location 

scope :before, lambda {|end_time| {:conditions => ["ends_at < ?",  Campaign.format_date(end_time)] }}
scope :after, lambda {|start_time| {:conditions => ["starts_at > ?", Campaign.format_date(start_time)] }}

# need to override the json view to return what full_calendar is expecting.
# http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

def as_json(options = {})
{
  :id => self.id,
  :title => self.name,
  :description => "",
  :start => starts_at.rfc822,
  :end => ends_at.rfc822,
  :allDay => false,
  :recurring => false,
  :url => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.campaign_path(friendly_id)
  }

end

 def self.format_date(date_time)
   Time.at(date_time.to_i).to_formatted_s(:db)
 end
```

**Script inside "Location" show.html.erb**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'month',

    loading: function(bool){
        if (bool)
            $('#loading').show();
        else
            $('#loading').hide();
    },

    // a future calendar might have many sources.
    eventSources: [{
        url: '/campaigns',
        data: { <%= @locations %> }, #added but not filtering as I had hoped
        color: 'blue',
        textColor: 'white',
        ignoreTimezone: false
    }],

    timeFormat: 'h:mm t{ - h:mm t} ',
    dragOpacity: "0.5",


    });
   });
```

Currently I am able to achieve in displaying the campaigns that belong to the given location on the display side in the location show with:

```
 <strong>Campaigns:</strong>
   <%= render partial: @campaigns %>
 </p>
```

And then in the location controller

```
  def show
   @campaigns = @location.campaigns
  end
```

I have tried for hours to figure this out with no luck in getting the same result to the calendar. Can someone please help me in figuring out what is required to filter the "Campaigns" that pertain to the viewing location??

Thanks!

Comment: I am wondering if I should be attempting to run the campaign retrieval through the locations controller since the locations has a relationship to campaigns: has_many :campaigns

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
 eventSources: [{
    url: '/campaigns',
    data: { 'location': <%= @locations %> }, <- try this like so
    color: 'blue',
    textColor: 'white',
    ignoreTimezone: false
}],
```